# How overflows work in solidity?

Tags: solidity, overflow

I just finished the Token Level in [Zeppelin's Ethernaut](https://ethernaut.zeppelin.solutions/) and in the end they explained that overflows are very common in solidity. I didn't even think about overflows, I just tried to steal the tokens.

This is the code they show:

---

Overflows are very common in solidity and must be checked for with control statements such as:

```
if(a + c > a) {
a = a + c;
}
```

An easier alternative is to use OpenZeppelin's SafeMath library that automatically checks for overflows in all the mathematical operators. The resulting code looks like this:

```
 a = a.add(c);
```

If there is an overflow, the code will revert.

---

I just can't understand what overflows in solidity are, can someone please give me a newbie explanation about what they are or point me an article where to look at. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/04/27/avoiding-integer-overflows-safemath-isnt-enough/:

Fixed-size integers have a range of values they can represent. For example, an 8-bit unsigned integer can store values between 0 and 255 (2^8-1). When the result of some arithmetic falls outside that supported range, an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) occurs.
On the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM), the consequence of an integer overflow is that the most significant bits of the result are lost. For example, when working with 8-bit unsigned integers, `255 + 1 = 0`. This is easier to see in binary, where `1111 1111 + 0000 0001` should be `1 0000 0000`, but because only 8 bits are available, the leftmost bit is lost, resulting in a value of `0000 0000`.

Intuitively, the effect of an integer overflow can be thought of as the value “wrapping around.”

Comment: Thanks a lot @smarx, great article, just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

An overflow is when the result of a binary operation (i.e., an operation with two operands), does not fit into the type of the operands (the larger type, if they are not identical).

For example:

```
uint8 a = 43;
uint16 b = 65500;
uint32 c = a + b;
```

In the above code, the result should be that `c` is set to `65543`.

The type of `c` can represent this value correctly, but the result of `a + b` is computed into `uint16` (the larger type of `a` and `b`), which cannot represent this value correctly.